# Preventing parent event fired when there's also Child control event fired

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I'm not quite sure how to entitle it, but, say I have 3 red `Rectangle` on the center of a `Canvas`.

If I click on a `Rectangle`, the color changes to blue, and if I click within the `Canvas` but not the `Rectangle`, each of the blue `Rectangle` switch color back to red.

My problem is this : If I make 2 `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, each for the `Rectangle`-s and another is for the `Canvas`, then if I click on the `Rectangle`, the `Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown` event also fired after the `Rectangle` one.

Question : How to prevent `Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown` (Parent control) event fired if there's a Child control which also Clicked.

Thanks.

UPDATE +code :

This is the `Rectangle` event :

```
private void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Change clicked rectangle color to blue
}
```

This is the `Canvas` event :

```
private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Change all Child rectangle color back to red
}
```

What I want in 1 sentence : If the "rectangle" event fires, the "canvas" one is prevented to fire.

Since the in-method code is not quite relevant to the question, then I remove it to make it look simpler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set [`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) to true in `Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown` handler

```
private void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

from MSDN

> Marking the event handled will limit the visibility of the routed event to listeners along the event route. The event does still travel the remainder of the route, but only handlers specifically added with HandledEventsToo true in the AddHandler(RoutedEvent, Delegate, Boolean) method call will be invoked in response

**EDIT**

As an alternative solution you can keep only `Canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler and remove one for `Rectangle` and then do something like this

```
private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
   {
       var myRectangle = e.OriginalSource as Rectangle;
       //your code for Rectangle clicked
   }
   else if (e.OriginalSource is Canvas)
   {
       var myCanvas = e.OriginalSource as Canvas;
       //your code for Canvas clicked
   }

}
```